# How do I turn a .0 float into an integer in python?

Tags: python, floating-point

I'm working on making a simple calculator to practice Tkinter in Python 3 and I want to be able to turn the output of an exponent equation like 2 to the 3rd from 8.0 to just 8 for aesthetic purposes. I tried using the strip function, but I'm a little confused.

```
import math
from tkinter import *

elif operation == "exponent":

    answer = str(math.pow(float(firstNum), 
    float(secondNum)))
    print(answer.strip("0"))
    print(answer.strip("."))
```

Comment: You can't start a program with `elif`.

Comment: `answer = int(math.pow(float(firstNum), float(secondNum)))`?

Comment: If you want to convert a float to an int, use the `int(...)` function.

Comment: Also please don't overuse tags. This question doesn't have anything to do with `tkinter`

Comment: You forgot the save the result of `strip()`.  BTW, use `answer = answer.strip(".0")`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all of that.
Say we had a float like `5.0`, we can use int to turn it into `5`.

```
int(5.0)
```

**output**

`5`